# Integrate TCAN4x5x into i.MX8 dts file

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, can-bus, device-tree

I've some trouble in enabling can device on my embedded platform based on iMX8 and YOCTO. To do that I would use the kernel driver already in the distro (TCAN4x5x). I've modified the *.dts file adding the following statements :

```
&ecspi2 { /* CAN */
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ecspi2>;
    status = "okay";

    tcan4x5x: tcan4x5x@0 {
        compatible = "ti,tcan4x5x";
        reg = <0>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
        bosch,mram-cfg = <0x0 0 0 16 0 0 1 1>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio1>;
        interrupts = <14 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
        device-state-gpios = <&gpio3 21 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        device-wake-gpios = <&gpio1 15 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        reset-gpios = <&gpio1 27 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    };
};
```

In according to the documentations in
[T-can driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/net/can/tcan4x5x.txt?h=linux-5.10.y)

and

```
+CONFIG_CAN_M_CAN=m 
+CONFIG_CAN_M_CAN_TCAN4X5X=m
```

to enable the driver into the kernel, patching "defconfig" file Now the dmesg command shows :

[image: dmesg output]

so in not clear what I've forgotten in *.dts

Some more details :

1. On the SOM the CANbs is not integrated
2. I've checked in [bosch can](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/net/can/bosch,m_can.yaml?h=linux-5.10.y) and I don't understand if the bosch can must be
   integrated into dts file

Thanks for sharing your idea

Comment: Why does your DT node look exactly like the bindings doc example? Did you simply copy the node from the doc verbatim? What have you done to investigate the error messages from the syslog? Why are you still posting images of text? Filtering the syslog with grep is providing only partial information; you could be ignoring other salient messages!

Comment: There is [a complete discussion on interfacing tcan4x5x to ecspi here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/862270/tcan4550-tcan4550rgyr-bootup-issue) it shows that ```hclk``` and ```cclk``` are defined in the device tree.